# TraceId is changing in every internal rest call through hystrix command

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, hystrix, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am facing the Issue with hystrix command, when my request flow from one service to another the tracIds is changing but it should be same.

I have 4 internal service call to get my resource but exceptions is coming, I want to track through traceId which I am returning in my response header, I am not able to track whole request from where it is flowing.

Comment: How do you call your services? Does library you use support hystrix? Did you configure it to use hystrix?

Comment: I am calling through resttemplates, yes it supports I am using netflix hystrix, Yes I have configured it to use hystrix